# c++ simple start a function with its own thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

i had once had a very simple one or two line code that would start a function with its own thread and continue running until application closed, c++ console app. lost the project it was in, and remember it was hard to find. cant find it online now. most example account for complicated multithreading situations. but i just need to open this one function in its own thread. hopefully someone knows what im talking about, or a similar solution.

eg.
start void abc in its own thread, no parameters

Comment: do you remember which library you were using? Boost? Pthread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example using [C++11 thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread):

```
#include <thread>

void abc(); // function declaration

int main()
{
  std::thread abcThread(abc); // starts abc() on a separate thread

  ....

  abcThread.join(); // waits until abcThread is done.
}
```

If you have no C++11 support, the same is possible using [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread.html), just by replacing `std::thread` by `boost::thread`.